# Is the sum of a float and its negation guaranteed to be zero?

Tags: floating-point

Using standard IEEE floating point, is `a + -a` guaranteed to be exactly `0` for any value of `a`?

I'd imagine `a` and `-a` have the exact same bit representation, minus the sign bit, so adding them together is guaranteed to result in `0` but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `a + (-a)` is guaranteed to produce exactly `+0.0` (in round-to-nearest) for every finite `a`, and NaN in the other cases.

For finite arguments, the principle that the result is the nearest float to the real result applies. The real result is 0, for which there are float representations, and +0.0 is favored when no sign makes more sense than the other.

Comment: That is true if `a + (-a)` is the actual calculation. Isn't there a risk, in some languages, that one of the values is in a wide register and the other in memory?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan It wouldn't be the case in Java(as I don't need to tell you). In C, compilers have existed that could do this (and the existence of these compilers is documented in http://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0701192 ) but a modern C99 compiler that defined `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` to 0, 1 or 2 would always produce `0.0`. OCaml suffers from double-rounding problems in some circumstances but will always compute `a + (-a)` as 0. C++ compilers do not seem to treat floating-point very seriously & they still have the problems that, for C compilers, should be confined to older compiler versions.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan The language-agnostic question says “Using standard IEEE floating-point”, and there is nothing standard about higher precision being used for some sub-expressions, but not others, outside the control of the programmer, so I feel that this caveat can be ignored in an answer to this question (although it would come up for a very slightly different one)

Comment: I agree that the answer is correct and complete for the question as asked, but there is a risk that some readers will over-generalize to e.g. their favorite C++ implementation.

Comment: Regarding the sign of the resulting zero, the relevant bit of IEEE 754 is: "When the sum of two operands with opposite signs (or the difference of two operands with like signs) is exactly zero, the sign of that sum (or difference) shall be +0 in all rounding-direction attributes except roundTowardNegative; under that attribute, the sign of an exact zero sum (or difference) shall be −0."